# Store gclid and bing utm tag in cookie, pass values to form

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, google-ads-api, bing

So I'm currently able to capture the GCLID value from visitors and pass this through to our forms just fine.  My question is, using the same scripts (attached below), is it possible to also capture a utm value as well? 
For example, if a visitor comes to our website from a Bing ad, the url will be something like www.example.com/?utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc

I need to be able to store the value of utm_source (bing) in a cookie, and pass this value to our forms.

Code that's working for me currently with the GCLID:

Store GCLID in cookie (before `</body>` tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(name, value, days){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000)); 
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getParam(p){
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + p + '=        ([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));}
    var gclid = getParam('gclid');
    if(gclid){
    var gclsrc = getParam('gclsrc');
    if(!gclsrc || gclsrc.indexOf('aw') !== -1){
        setCookie('gclid', gclid, 90);
    }
}
</script>
```

Pass value to form (in header):

```
<script> 
window.onload = function getGclid() {        
                document.getElementById("00N3100000H5IBe").value = (name = new    
                RegExp('(?:^|;\\s*)gclid=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? 
                name.split(",")[1] : "";
            }
// window.onload() may not be supported by all browsers.  
// If you experience problems submitting the GCLID as a
// hidden field, consider using an alternate method to
// call this function on page load.
</script>
```

I am able to modify the current scripts to capture the utm value but then it won't capture the gclid value. So far I have been unable to do both.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated. Please let me know if I need to better explain things.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code below puts the GCLID code in the hidden field OR the UTM_Source.
I have this all in the body as you first need to set the cookie and then read it out.

Good luck!

NOTE: the 'Field7' is the ID of the hidden field on my form.You will have to change that to your form.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(name, value, days){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getParam(p){
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + p + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
function readCookie(name) {
var n = name + "=";
var cookie = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < cookie.length;i++) {      
  var c = cookie[i];      
  while (c.charAt(0)==' '){c = c.substring(1,c.length);}      
  if (c.indexOf(n) == 0){return c.substring(n.length,c.length);}
}
return null;
}
// Define the variables
var gclid = getParam('gclid');
var utm_source = getParam('utm_source');

// Check if there is a GCLID first, then check if there is a utm_source
if(gclid){
alert(gclid);
      setCookie('gclid', gclid, 90);
        } else if(utm_source) {
alert(utm_source);
        setCookie('utm_source', utm_source, 90);
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> // Now set the hidden field on the form by looking for the correct cookie name
window.onload = function() {      
    if (gclid) {
 document.getElementById('Field7').value = readCookie('gclid');
} else if (utm_source) {
 document.getElementById('Field7').value = readCookie('utm_source');
}
}
</script>
```